# Populate Excel unidimensional Array with data from a list in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a list : `var families = new List<string>();`.
 And I have created an unidimensional array with the length of the list: `var a = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), families.Count(), 1);`
How can I populate the Array "a" with the values of the list in order t use that array to put values into a range?
Hope that my question is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
string[] a = families.ToArray();
```

If you wanted to create the array without filling it, you would simply write:

```
var a = new string[families.Count];
```

This is equivalent to `Array.CreateInstance`. You would use the latter only if the type was given in a `Type` variable. This would allow you to determine the type of the array at runtime; however, here simply use `new knownType[count]`.

Or `new object[count]`, but its not clear to me why you should want to weakly type your array.

If you need a 2-dimensional array, with the second dimension having a length of one, you can write:

```
var a = new string[families.Count, 1];
// OR if you really need an object array
var a = new object[families.Count, 1];
for (int i = 0; i < families.Count; i++) {
    a[i, 0] = families[i];
}
```

Don't use `families.Count()`. This calls a LINQ extension method. No need to do this here, since `List<T>` has a much faster `Count` property (`families.Count` without the `()`).

Comment: Thank you so much!. I'm an architect, new to programming, but trying to use C# language for improving my quantity take-offs from 3D models. So, your information, after reading and trying to understand every concept, has been very very useful for a newbie like me. Cheers!